# How can I set height=100% without any content in css?

Tags: html, css

sorry for my English...
I want to make sidebar 100% height of the page. I set html:100% and then height: 100%. but as you see in screenshot the sidebar does not working. and the height is equal to the height of content inside that.

[image]

this is css code i wrote for that. I also use viewpoints for sidebar..............

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

body p {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}


.main {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #243E36;
    color: #F1F7ED;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E0EEC6;
    width: 30%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

header h1 {
    color: #C2A83E;
}

header p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    word-spacing: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}

section {
    color: #212121;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

article {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    float: left;
}

article h2 {
    padding: 15px;
}

article p {
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #7CA982;
    text-align: center;
}

aside {
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #E0EEC6;
    float: left;
}

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.group {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container group">
        <div class="main">
            <!-- Header -->
            <header>
                <h1>My Personal NoteBook</h1>
                <p>Welcome to my page</p>
            </header>

            <!-- Notes -->
            <section class="group">
                <article>
                    <h2>Title 1</h2>
                    <p>Posted on 2020/07/23</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, sequi iusto! Facere, quos
                        tempore veritatis sit ratione iste perferendis quod possimus voluptatem, quam, non similique
                        labore quas adipisci corporis libero!</p>
                </article>
            </section>
            <!-- Footer -->
            <footer>
                <p>&copy;2020 My Nootbook</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <aside style="height:100vh;">
            <h1>SideBar</h1>
        </aside>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it is hard to give an answer without code, but you can try `flex` or `grid` for this layout.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: I put css codes

Comment: Can you put the html just for an idea where each elements live? You can remove the whole text

Comment: I also put html code

Comment: The issue in your code is because you used float, once you used float, the height will take as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by using inline CSS in your sidebar div element

`

```
   <div class="sidenav" style="height:100vh;position: fixed;">
             <a href="#about">About</a>
             <a href="#services">Services</a>
             <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
             <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>"
```

`
I hope this example will give you a better idea.

Comment: Yes but as the height of the page grows, it does not work

Comment: Please try using position fixed for the sidebar div. I have edited the code refer my example.

Answer (score 1):

You issues is you have used 2 floats elements, and float elements won't respect height:100%.

**Solution #1:** Float 1 div, and another using margin-left

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
.c-container {
  height: 100%;
}
.c-content {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}
.c-sidebar {
  margin-left: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-container">
<div class="c-content ">
content
</div>
<div class="c-sidebar">
sidebar
</div>
</div>
```

**Flex solution:**

```css
html,body {
  height: 100vh;
}
.c-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
.c-content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.c-sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-container">
<div class="c-content ">
content
</div>
<div class="c-sidebar">
sidebar
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I can solve this by using flex but I want to know the reason for this issue and find the way for fix that

Comment: Actually it has nothing with flex, can you provide the code a little bit more?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/vsLd49a8/ I don't see any issue, the sidebar displays good with height.

Comment: What do you want? left right layout without using flex? I think you can consider using 1 float div and another sidebar with margin-left, but not float 2 elements